# Return value where row value is partial match to column header - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm aiming to return a single value from two columns. The two columns I'm selecting from are `Near_Group_Red` and `Near_Group_Blue`. The rule for selecting a specific value from these columns is based off `Item`. Where the value in `Item` is Red or Blue, I want to grab the value from the corresponding `Near_Group` cols.

```
d = {'Item': ["Red", "Blue", "Blue", "Red"],
     'Near_Group_Red': [0, 0, 0, 0],
     'Near_Group_Blue': [1, 1, 1, 0],
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

cols = df.columns.difference(['Red','Blue'])
mask = df[cols].eq(df['Item'], axis=0)
df['SELECT'] = np.where(mask.any(axis=1), mask.idxmax(axis=1), 'no match')
```

intended output:

```
   Item  Near_Group_Red  Near_Group_Blue SELECT
0   Red               0                1      0
1  Blue               0                1      1
2  Blue               0                1      1
3   Red               0                0      0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are only `Red` and `Blue` values use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['SELECT'] = np.where(df['Item'].eq('Red'), df['Near_Group_Red'], df['Near_Group_Blue'])
```

If possible another values use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
df['SELECT'] = np.select([df['Item'].eq('Red'), 
                          df['Item'].eq('Blue')], 
                        [df['Near_Group_Red'], 
                         df['Near_Group_Blue']],
                         default=None)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try via `where()` method:

```
df['SELECT']=df['Near_Group_Red'].where(df['Item'].eq('Red'),df['Near_Group_Blue'])
```

If there are more values in 'Item' column then you can try:

```
m=df['Item'].isin(['Red','Blue'])
df.loc[m,'SELECT']=(df.loc[m,'Near_Group_Red']
                      .where(df.loc[m,'Item'].eq('Red'),df.loc[m,'Near_Group_Blue']))
```